# GAMS default Solver doesn't use much of my RAM and CPU

Tags: cplex, gams, cplex-python-api

I noticed that when I run the solver via the GAMS IDE or Python API I don't use more than ~33% of my RAM. Is there an artificial barrier which I can put up or disable?

[image]

Comment: Why the driveby downvote?

Comment: Which solver are you using?

Comment: Not sure about the reason you want the model to use more memory, but -- of course -- small models use less memory than big ones. CPU percentage can be increased by using more threads (default in GAMS is 1 thread). BTW that will also increase memory usage.

Comment: @KevinDalmeijer 
IBM ILOG CPLEX   32.2.0 rc62c018 Released Aug 26, 2020 WEI x86 64bit/MS Window
--- GAMS/Cplex Link licensed for continuous and discrete problems.
Cplex 12.10.0.0

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you. I let it be like that since i am only making a comparison and not striving for maximum speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ErwinKalvelagen pointed out: by default gams cplex uses only 1 thread which results in a low usage of the pc ressources.

In order to change this one has to increase the thread  number so that multiple cores can be used at the same time:
https://support.gams.com/solver:multiple_cplex_threads

Answer (score 3):

This analogy might help: CPU usage is like the power output of an engine - more is better in terms of performance. Memory usage is more like the heat produced by the engine - too much heat, aka memory capacity exceeded, and the engine breaks down.

There is simply no reason in trying to increase or even max out memory usage.